# PHP Array to SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Attempting to convert a PHP array to an SQL query but it does not seem to be updating the data. Any ideas? I can't seem to get anything out of debug dump that might be helpful as to why.

```
$terms = count($getResource);
foreach ($getResource as $field => $value)
{
    $terms--;
    $prepareStr .= $field . ' = :' . $field;
    if ($terms)
    {
        $prepareStr .= ', ';
    }
}

$terms = count($getResource);
$executeStr .= "':settlementID'=>'$getSettlementID', ";
foreach ($getResource as $field => $value)
{
    $terms--;
    $executeStr .= "':" . $field . "'=>'" . $value . "'";
    if ($terms)
    {
        $executeStr .= ', ';
    }
}


try 
{
    //update resources
    $sqlupdate = $db->prepare("UPDATE settlements SET " . $prepareStr . " WHERE id = :settlementID");

    $sqlupdate->execute(array($executeStr));
} 
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$sqlupdate->debugDumpParams();
}
```

Comment: You need to bind a value for `settlementID`

Comment: $executeStr .= "':settlementID'=>'$getSettlementID', ";

This is not sufficient?

Comment: Why pass you `array(string)` to `execute`? Just pass an array of values: `array(':settlementID' => $getSettlementID)`

Answer (score 0):

Named placeholders are redundant in this scenario.

```
// Assume $getResource has key-value structure for update
$list = array_map(function($field){
  return "$field = ?";
}, array_keys($getResource));
$strData = implode(", ", $list);

$params = array_values($getResource);
$params[] = $settlementId;

$prepareSql = "UPDATE $tableName SET $strData WHERE id = ?";

$sth = $db->prepare($prepareSql);
$sth->execute($params);
```